# Unregister a custom node type in Magnolia

Tags: magnolia

Does anyone know if it is possible to unregister a custom node type?

For example, I have created a custom node type say "mgnl:product", which is created on start up, then I want to remove this "mgnl:product" since I won't be using it anymore. Cause currently, even if I remove it from the xml, then on startup, when I try to add a content node in JCR Browser, I can still see this node type in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find your custom type inside `custom_nodetypes.xml`. This file is  located under `${magnolia.home}` folder:

```
${magnolia.home}/repositories/magnolia/repository/nodetypes/custom_nodetypes.xml
```

Just remove the `<nodeType />` definition corresponding to your custom type an restart server. You need to also remove it from your `mgnl-nodetypes/magnolia-*-nodetypes.xml` files, so it won't be added again.

Comment: Oh nice thank you! I didn't know such file exists! :D